# Atmel C compiler manual?

Tags: embedded, microprocessors, atmel

I'm just getting started with the Attiny84 on AVR Studio 5 (based off of Visual Studio).  However, I cant find the C programmers manual for it so I can figure out how to write ISR's, address GPIO pins, etc... Any ideas where I could find the manual for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the official manual is located here (provided by Atmel Applications Engineer):

http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/modules.html

It had all the information I needed to get up and running.

Comment: Useful link, but that is the documentation for the C library not the compiler.  Up-voting nonetheless due to its usefulness.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking at the [AVR Studio 5 web page](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/avr_studio_5/default.asp?source=cms&icn=hmap1-AVR_STUDIO&ici=apr_2011), it looks as though it can use the GCC compiler--not sure what other compilers it might be able to use.

The GCC compiler is an open-source compiler used for many platforms, so documentation is available for that from many places on the Internet.

The other thing I could suggest is taking a different approach: start by looking at some publicly available code for the AVR. AVR Studio 5 is in beta, but I expect it wouldn't be hugely different from what has already been in use for several years (AVR Studio 4 etc). [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/) is a good resource for looking at AVR code done by others, for a wide range of applications.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a bit of hunting down, but according to [this press release](http://ir.atmel.com/releasedetail.cfm?ReleaseID=553357), the integrated compiler is GCC.  The GCC documentation is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ for all versions.

In the 4.6.0 release, AVR specific sections are:

- [3.17.2 AVR Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html)
- [6.37.8 AVR Variable Attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes)

The Atmel AVR Studio 5 web page claims that it has several hundred example projects included, I am sure than many of them include interrupt handler examples.

Answer (score 0):

I too am just getting started with AVR Studio 5. When doing GPIO, interrupts etc, I think you will want to leverage the code already provided in the ASF (Atmel Software Framework). Under the Project menu use the "Select Drivers from ASF..." to select the pieces you need. Alternately you can load sample projects targeted for your processor. I found the [AVR Studio screencasts](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/avr_studio_5/default.asp?source=cms&icn=hmap1-AVR_STUDIO&ici=may_2011) on the Atmel site (they are also on YouTube) worth watching.

Comment: None of the code in the ASF was for the ATtiny84 when I looked, it was all for the ATmega's, I beleive.  I'm not sure how transferable it is.  I found that between the datasheets and the official manual (nongnu), I was able to get up and running quite easily.